# Initialize NSArray with size

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

How do I initialize an NSArray with size only so to use a for loop to fill it later? My for loop would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
    myArray[i] = someData;
}
```

Comment: So all the answers are saying that I must use a NSMutableArray as opposed to an NSArray. Does that mean I cannot directly use an NSArray for solving this problem?

Comment: An NSArray is immutable meaning that its contents cannot be edited in the future. This also prevents any objects from being added to or removed from the array, so its length will always remain constant. An NSMutableArray on the other hand is mutable in that objects can always be added or removed at any given time even after initialisation.

Comment: My restriction is that I don't want the size to change inadvertently but at the same time, I want user to be able to update the values. The array is a Boolean array. I am coming from Java so you understand my troubles. The NSMutableArray means the size can grow. So how do I prevent inadvertent change in the size while allowing for the values to be changeable?

Comment: @KatedralPillon You can't do that with any of the built-in classes. You could wrap `NSMutableArray` in your own class or subclass it if you like.

Comment: If you're just storing BOOLs, you could use a C array.

Comment: But it sounds like you'll probably want a custom data class with a public interface, which (privately) uses an NSMutableArray to store its data.

Comment: As @AaronBrager said, you can just use a C array instead. If you don't need any of the methods in NSArray then that would be your best option. Otherwise, use `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to initialize it with a specific size - you can add objects later:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    [myArray addObject:someData];
}
```

There are slight performance gains if you know the size ahead of time:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
```

But this is optional.

Answer (score 2):

`NSNull` is the class used to represent an unset, invalid or non-existent object. Therefore you can pad the array to a specific size using instances of this class.

```
NSUInteger sizeOfArray = 10;
NSMutableArray *someArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
    [someArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

Further, you can't use the syntax `someArray[i] = xyz;` if the value at position `i` doesn't exist, as it will cause an out of bounds error.

Comment: Is there any way to alloc an array so later I can do `array[i] = obj` without adding something before it with `addObject`?